# Presentation recommendation

Tags: presentation

I've been asked to design some on-screen graphics for an event next year. It will be spoof game show for fun. However I'm need some help trying to find an appropriate piece of software for the presentation.

The game show will be based on the UK '80's show 'Family Fortunes'. For those who aren't familiar this is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

[image]

I know it's nothing special, but I've been asked to keep it as authentic as possible.

Thanks in advance,

Jack